# Recursive Function to Produce Constrained List of Integer Partitions

Tags: python, recursion, mathematics

I have modified a recursive function designed to print all the integer partitions of a positive integer to create a function that returns all partitions of the "number" parameter if they include a number contained in the "interesting" parameter. I would like to use this for very large numbers (10-50 million), but am getting errors referring to the recursion depth. My question is whether there is a way to do this more efficiently by recursion, and if not, whether there is another way to do this.

```
def partition(number, interesting): # returns all the partitions of number that are included in the interesting list
    answer = set()
    if number in interesting:
        answer.add((number, ))
    
    for x in range(1, number):
        if x in interesting: 
            for y in partition(number - x, interesting):
                answer.add(tuple(sorted((x, ) + y)))
    return answer
```

Comment: If you have more of the program you haven't posted, please include it. Also, please rename the question to reflect what you're doing with the application, not your review concerns.

Comment: What do you do with your answer?  You are returning a `Set[Tuple[int,...]]`, but do you need to return the entire set at once, or could you use return the set elements one at a time using a generator?  Is this a programming challenge?  If so post a link to the problem, as well as the full problem description in the question, including limits, such as the number of interesting numbers, as well as their ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not designed for recursion. To avoid stack overflows there is a limit

```
In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.getrecursionlimit()
Out[3]: 1000
```

So we can easily design a test that will fail

```
In [4]: partition(1000, {1})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-884568e60acd> in <module>()
----> 1 partition(1000, {1})

<ipython-input-1-60a0eb582d3c> in partition(number, interesting)
      6     for x in range(1, number):
      7         if x in interesting:
----> 8             for y in partition(number - x, interesting):
      9                 answer.add(tuple(sorted((x, ) + y)))
     10     return answer

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-1-60a0eb582d3c> in partition(number, interesting)
      6     for x in range(1, number):
      7         if x in interesting:
----> 8             for y in partition(number - x, interesting):
      9                 answer.add(tuple(sorted((x, ) + y)))
     10     return answer

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

You may increase the recursion limit

```
In [5]: sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

In [6]: partition(1000, {1})
Out[6]: 
{(1, ...
```

but that is only applicable if your numbers are guaranteed to be in a certain range. Most probably you should implement a non-recursive solution. For 10-50 million you have to.

If your problem e. g. guarantees `1 <= number <= 500` you should still do some assertions in your function

```
assert 1 <= number <= 500
```